# Angular JS How to get all rows of a repeater with Protractor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, repeater, angularjs-ng-repeat, protractor

I have a table with all users and I want to search for a user with the column {{user.name}} === 'X'. When I found the right row I want to delete the entry with a click on the last column of the row.

```
element(by.repeater('user in allUsers')).then(function(rows) {
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; ++i) {
    // if the right row is found click on the last column to delete it
  } 
});
```

I get an TypeError: Object # has no method 'then'

I found my solution here but that is still the old syntax

Comment: I forgot the link github.com/angular/protractor/issues/147

Answer (score 7):

You forgot to call the `all` function:

```
element.all(by.repeater('user in allUsers')).then(function(rows) {
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The error is gone now. Protractor waits till the data from the server is displayed, but the function(rows) is not called.

Comment: This looks right to me - are you sure the function isn't being called? Are you sure you're treating `rows` as an array of WebElements?

Comment: I just put an console.log('test'); into the function but it is not working. The callback function is not called.

Comment: Isn't that the sign that your page doesn't have such a repeater?

Comment: No the repeater is on the page. Because     var rows = element.all(by.repeater('user in allUsers'));
        expect(rows.count ()).toEqual(16); is working as expected

Comment: I'm having the same issue where the "then" call is never made